# llvm-cov and "unknown command line argument: -format=html"

Tags: linux, code-coverage, llvm-cov

I did a code coverage test using the llvm utility. After that, I needed to do a html cover file. I used the command

```
llvm-cov show test -instr-profile=default.profdata -format=html > report.html
```

Then I received the following error:

> Unknown command line argument '-format=html'.

How I can solve my problem ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-cov.html) the syntax is

```
llvm-cov show [options] -instr-profile PROFILE BIN [-object BIN,…] [[-object BIN]] [SOURCES]
```

so the option `-format=html` needs to go before the profile and binary name.

```
llvm-cov show -format=html -instr-profile default.profdata test > report.html
```